# Phrase meaning : they are to

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> The knowledge of regional languages is necessary for bank officers because they are to understand what their customers say.

I tried google for meaning/usage of the phrase *they are to* as used in above given sentence but couldn't find anything relevant, I doubt if any such phrase even exists. To my hears using *have* instead of *are* sounds better. Please tell if the phrase *they are to* used in above sentence is correct ? If yes, Does it imply the same meaning as using *have* instead of *are* ?

Comment: http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/be-to-verb-are-to-get read this, and https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/288200/have-to-be-or-are-to-be-difference-in-meaning may they help u understand this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *Merriam-Webster* site provides [an explanation of this usage](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/be-to-verb-are-to-get), better than one I could create (and as suggested in the comments).  And you could try doing a search of *am/is/are*.

In case the link disappears, this is what it states:

> The construction “be + to + verb” is a formal construction that is used either a) to give an instruction or command, or b) to tell what is going to happen in the future.
>
> In the following three sentences, the “be + to + verb” construction signals that these are commands. This construction makes the sentences sound serious and formal.
>
> You are to do your homework without watching any TV.
>   The students are not to travel by subway without a friend.
>   [Patient speaking to nurse] The doctor says that I’m to make an appointment to come back next month.
>
> In the following sentences, the “be + to + verb” construction tells us that these sentences are about planned or scheduled events.
>
> The plane is to take off at 9 pm.
>   The new kitchen cabinets are to arrive before December 20th.
>   Their house is to be sold right away.
>
> Again, these sentences sound formal. If we change the verb construction to “be + going + to + verb,” they retain the same meaning but sound less formal.
>
> The plane is going to take off at 9 am.
>   The new kitchen cabinets are going to arrive before December 20th.
>   Their house is going to be sold right away.